# React overwrites all states on setState

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have the following setup:

```
this.state = {
  values: {
    id: null,
    name: "",
    unitName: "",
    unitCategory: ""
  }
};
```

and when I change a value in a field in a form I have the following `handleChange` function:

```
this.setState({
  values: {
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }
});
```

the problem is - this removes all other values from the `values` object in my state and only leaves the one that's being modified (i.e. `<input name="name" />`).

How could I retain all other values?

**Edit**
The code now looks like:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  console.log(prevState.values);
  return {
    values: {
      ...prevState.values,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }
  };
});
```

The `console.log(prevState.values)` returns:

`{id: 2, name: "Humidity", unitName: "himidity", unitCategory: "%"}`

Which is how it should be, but when I spread it in `values` object, I get:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use spread syntax to *spread the other properties* into state:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  values: {
    ...prevState.values,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  }
}));
```

This also utilizes the callback with `setState` to ensure the previous state is correctly used. If your project doesn't support object spread syntax yet, you could use `Object.assign`:

```
values: Object.assign({}, prevState.values, {
  [e.target.name]: [e.target.value]
})
```

This does essentially the same thing. It starts with an empty object to avoid mutation, and copies `prevState.values`'s keys and values into the object, then copies the key `[e.target.name]` and its value into the object, overwriting the old key and value pair.

---

Also, I'm not sure why you're doing all this:

```
this.state = {
  values: {
    id: this.state.values.id ? this.state.values.id : null,
    name: this.state.values.name ? this.state.values.name : "",
    unitName: this.state.values.unitName ? this.state.values.unitName : "",
    unitCategory: this.state.values.unitCategory? this.state.values.unitCategory: "
  }
};
```

When you set initial state in the constructor, just give the initial value, your ternary operator will never give you the true condition:

```
this.state = {
  values: {
    id: null,
    name: '',
    unitName: '',
    unitCategory: ''
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, please check the edit to my post.

Comment: @Xeen Try to add `e.persist()` as the very first line in your`handleChange`.